# Spring Security OAuth2 and React SPA

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, microservices, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to get my head around spring security and OAuth 2.0. I have created an auth microservice which I want to use with my React SPA application where I have a login popup and register screen.

Should I be creating another microservice (e.g user) which provides user management apis (e.g. login/register) which then calls the auth microservice or should I be creating these apis in the auth microservice directly?

Ideally, I'd like to avoid the implicit grant flow as I don't want to create a separate UI application to handle login. I'm thinking creating the user microservice will allow me to use the password grant flow and reuse the existing login/registers screens which would be ideal.

Would appreciate any pointers.